# Do lifeforms contain machine spirits?

Tags: warhammer-40k

It's my understanding that the mechanicum believes all machines function thanks to the machine spirits residing within them, which they revere.

I also understand that they believe organics are just carbon-based machines rather than iron-based machines.

But I also understand that they have a poor opinion of organic bodies in many cases, ranging from simple dislike to outright contempt.

There seems to be some cognitive dissonance here; "We hate biology.  Biology is just inefficient machinery. We love all machines."

If lifeforms are machines without machine spirits somehow, that would explain it.  So do lifeforms contain machine spirits?

Or is all this heretical and I should report to the nearest Inquisitor?

Answer (score 6):

### Maybe

Adeptus Mechanicus doesn't hate biology: in fact, there is a whole part of the AM that specializes in studying the biology, medicine and genetics called Magos Biologis or [Genetor](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Genetor):

> For the most part, genetors differ little from other Tech-priests -- they bear the same manner of augmetic implants, venerate information and understanding as the manifestation of divinity, and engage upon the Quest for Knowledge in much the same way.

> The difference is that they are not so quick to judge flesh and blood as inferior to steel and plasma and **view living creatures as extremely complex and adaptable machines.**

The [Mysteries of Adeptus Mechanicus](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Cult_Mechanicus) state that the soul can be created only by the Omnissiah. At the same time, they believe that Machine Spirits are fragments of the Machine God. If so, especially if you'd follow Genetor's line of thought, you could say that human soul is a special kind of a Machine Spirit, since it is a gift from god.

Answer (score 5):

The Mechanicus does not believe that ALL machines work thanks to the Machine Spirits. Machine Spirits are what's left over from the Dark Ages of Technologies artificial intelligences. Machine Spirits are not artificial intelligences, as those are forbidden, but for our comprehension simply extremly sophisticated computer programs. There are a lot of machines without machine spirits, e.g. the simple Lasgun does not contain a Machine Spirit. However, more advanced machinery, such as Thunderhawks, Drop Pods, Titans and so on use those sophisticated programs in order to work.

From the Lexicanum [article on Machine Spirits](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Machine_spirit):

> A machine spirit is what the Imperium refers to as the inner workings and automated systems within their technology. These are distinct from forbidden Abominable Intelligence, as they lack the ability to enhance themselves.

The phrase "The Flesh is weak", which is regularely being used by the adepts of the Mechanicus, simply refers to it's shorter lifespan and ease to break compared to metal. Therefore, the adepts of the Mechanicus try to improve their body with metal and machines in order to make it more durable and use the advantages of the machines like harddisks that can retain every memory compared to the human brain.

As for if the humans have machine spirits, I'd answer no, based on some [universal laws of the Cult Mechanicus](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Universal_Law):

> 10th: The Soul is the Conscience of Sentience.
>
> 11th: A Soul can be bestowed only by the Omnissiah.
>
> 12th: The Soulless Sentience is the Enemy of All.
>
> 14th: The Machine Spirit guards the Knowledge of the Ancients.

As artificial intelligences are forbidden (the term AI refers to Abomidable Intelligence) and are, contrary to humans, soulless, they are the enemy. So, they draw a clear line between beings with a soul (i.e. humans) and machines with a spirit (that guard the knowledge of the ancients).

Comment: You made me realise I don't have the slightest idea what a machine spirit actually is. Back then, I thought I read somewhere that even your bolter will perform better on the field if the machine spirit is pleased and healthy.

Comment: @Clockwork It is. The Mechanicus not really understanding that the Machine Spirits is simply a computer program refers to maintenance work on the Bolter as the Machine Spirit being pleased and healthy. That can be simply cleaning the weapon but also resolving issues in the programm. However, they don't have a documentation like our IT department has but it's a ritual, stating that if issue X appears, you need to do ritual K. Basically, it's connect to the programm and changing a conf-file from Shoot="N" to Shoot="Y"

Comment: @Clockwork Imagine a member of a primitive people watching someone open up a broken iphone, swapping the battery and the glass, and then turning it on. They'll see a machine with lots of colors, that can make sound and flash light, and sometimes even _speak_. The machine wasn't doing anything, and now it is doing things - the rituals done by the man in the blue shirt pleased it.

Comment: In a way, the Mechanicus is a form of extremely advanced [_Cargo Cult_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult).

Comment: @T.Sar Suddenly, part of me is a bit disappointed. I always found the story of "self-fighting Land Raider without any pilot thanks to a machine spirit, and no artificial intelligence heresy" very strange but interesting. Now it turns out they're just a bunch of primitives who know how to read the man page but don't know the nature of what they operate.

Comment: @Clockwork It is a bit more complicated: thanks to the fact that the belief affects reality some machines indeed start getting some sort of personality, exactly because they are being taken care of. The more complicated machine - the stronger spirit - things like titans of ancient tanks are positively sentient and temperamental.

Comment: @Yasskier So basically da little humies got sum learnin' from da orkz after all?

Comment: @Clockwork That and the machines are able to learn and adapt. Specially something like an Imperial Knight or Titan will imprint upon its "driver" as they are linked. But even a tank or a servo armour will learn how the driver / wearer behaves and adapt. Thing is, when the person inside changes, the machine spirit still behaves like for the old guy... and as a lot of machines are very old, they had a lot of "owners" they've learnt to adapt to and will finally have kind of a personality.

Comment: @Clockwork Would you like to know more? Ask a question and we will gladly answer for everybody to find.

Comment: @Shade Problem is there's already questions about machine spirit, so I'll have to check out if they allow me to better understand, and see what I can ask if not.

Comment: Fundamentally they are AIs. The Imperium is one giant self-contradiction - violently condemning computers, psychic powers, and genetic mutation, yet only able to exist because of them and the bureaucratic loopholes that allow them to exist.

Comment: @OrangeDog A machine spirit is what the Imperium refers to as the inner workings and automated systems within their technology. These are distinct from forbidden Abominable Intelligence, as they lack the ability to enhance themselves. - Lexicanum: Machine Spirits

Comment: @Shade I'm considering of asking a rather generic question about the many things that can be attributed to a "machine spirit", in order to get a detailed somewhat "list answer" that would explain what are the many things that the Imperium linked to the machine having a spirit that performs better (be it low level automated machinery, to basic weapon maintenance, or even collective belief that make it true). Do you think that would be an okay question to ask, or would it be closed (as duplicate or too broad)? Because there's been several questions already, even if I still don't understand.

Comment: @Clockwork Very difficult to answer that question. A simple question can lead to a very long answer, e.g. "What is a machine spirit" would very probably lead to a either very short or very long answer, depending on how "motivated" the answerer is. And even if it's closed as "too broad" or "several questions", you can edit your question and it can be reopened.